# Highlight selected objects in LibreOffice Draw

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, libreoffice, selection, highlighting

Is there some way to see which objects are selected in LibreOffice Draw, when selecting multiple objects with Shift+LeftClick?

Compare these screenshots from Libreoffice and Powerpoint (at slightly different state of editing):

[image]

In powerpoint, it is obvious that the four circles are selected. In Libreoffice it is anyones guess which of the objects are selected. As a result I repeatedly accidentially selected something other then the circles, without any visual feedback warning me about it.

The highlight would be the same for countless combinations of selected objects; If the "b4" circle is not selected for instance, one will not notice until changing something. For trivial examples this is only a minor annoyance, but for larger numbers of objects (e.g. changing the color of all blue circles in [image]) it quickly becomes inconvenient.

Is it possible with Libreoffice to determine the selected objects in a manner similarly convenient as seen in Powerpoint?

Comment: The 8 green squares clearly show you have the whole drawing (cube) selected in Draw.

Comment: No, I have not. Only the four gray circles are selected, the same as in powerpoint. The same goes for the inline image – there two only a few circles are selected, but if all were selected, the selection-rectangle would be the same. This ambiguity of the visual feedback is what I am asking about.

Comment: @kdb Aside: The selection rectangle tightly encloses the selected objects. In your second screenshot you must at least have the text b1 selected as well as the grey circles.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, and I agree it's a usability problem. One (laborious) workaround is to group the selected objects, then `Enter group` - now the non-selected objects are faded slightly. Another might be to drag the objects (clicking on one you know is in the group) and then undo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the bugreport linked by [Joe P](https://superuser.com/users/430424/joe-p), a better workaround was brought up after I posted my examples there: Pressing "F8" to toggle "points-mode", where the highlights look pretty much like in Powerpoint.

A followup comment however disputes this method as a workaround that mixes functions that should be separate, but it is certainly at least a *better* workaround.

Comment: Definitely better. Good find.

Answer (score 1):

According to bug report [74364 – EDITING: Selecting multiple draw objects should show (unselectable) handles for all objects](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74364) this isn't possible.

I agree it's a usability problem.

One (laborious) workaround is to group the selected objects, then `Enter group` - now the non-selected objects are faded slightly. Another might be to drag the objects (clicking on one you know is in the group) and then undo.